# Default matrix number of columns and rows in R

Tags: r, matrix, default-value

In R, I can create a matrix with `matrix()`, which has the function definition:

```
function (data = NA, nrow = 1, ncol = 1, byrow = FALSE, dimnames = NULL)
{ ... }
```

This suggests that the default value for number of rows (`nrow`) and columns (`ncol`) are 1.

So why does the following break? Why does specifying the same default values of `1` result in a different matrix?

```
> matrix(1:9)
      [,1]
 [1,]    1
 [2,]    2
 [3,]    3
 [4,]    4
 [5,]    5
 [6,]    6
 [7,]    7
 [8,]    8
 [9,]    9

> matrix(1:9, ncol=1, nrow=1)
     [,1]
[1,]    1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user-facing `base::matrix` calls an [internal function](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/af7f52f70101960861e5d995d3a4bec010bc89e6/src/main/array.c#L63-L199):

```
matrix
# function (data = NA, nrow = 1, ncol = 1, byrow = FALSE, dimnames = NULL) 
# {
#     if (is.object(data) || !is.atomic(data)) 
#         data <- as.vector(data)
#     .Internal(matrix(data, nrow, ncol, byrow, dimnames, missing(nrow), 
#         missing(ncol)))
# }
# <bytecode: 0x000000000b802e88>
# <environment: namespace:base>
```

In particular, note that the last two arguments passed to the internal function are flags indicating if the row and / or column dimensions were specified: `missing(nrow), missing(ncol)`. The fact that these parameters have default values does not preclude them from being "missing". For example,

```
f <- function(x = 1, y = 2) {
    cat(sprintf(
        "missing(x): %s\nmissing(y): %s\n", 
        missing(x), 
        missing(y)
    ))
}

f()
# missing(x): TRUE
# missing(y): TRUE
```

---

Since the "missing-ness" of these arguments is not affected by the fact that they have default values, that logic can be handled independently, as [is done here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/af7f52f70101960861e5d995d3a4bec010bc89e6/src/main/array.c#L93-L131).

Comment: In a sense; I'm not sure "overrides" would be the most appropriate term, but essentially default values and "missing-ness" are orthogonal properties of the arguments. Because of this, the internal function knows whether or not each of these two arguments were actually specified, and can distinguish between the two scenarios of **(A)** `ncol = 1, nrow = 1` & not user-specified and **(B)** `ncol = 1, nrow = 1` & user-specified; even thought the `ncol, nrow` values are the same.

Comment: Accidentally deleted my prior comment. Thanks for the help!